# Add line break/new line in IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb

How do I add a line-break/new-line in IRB/Ruby? The book I'm learning from shows this code:

```
print "2+3 is equal to "
print 2 + 3
```

without telling how to go to the second line without hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>, which obviously just runs the program.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. IRB is a repl, it s meant to run each line one line at a time. There is no reason/sense behind trying to run both of those lines "at the same time". If you want to run an entire script, put it in a file and `ruby <file>`, don't use IRB.

Comment: You can use semicolon `;` to chain your statements. And also you can interpolate that as `print "2+3 is equal to #{2+3}"`.

Comment: Semicolons don't "chain" statements, they let them be written on the same line, but they remain separate statements. And, while we _can_ use semicolons, they're not idiomatic and they lead to code that isn't written clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That book might be taking very tiny steps to introducing this idea:

```
print "Continues..."
puts "(Up to here)"
```

The `print` function just outputs to the terminal exactly what it's given. The `puts` function does the same but also adds a newline, which is what you want.

The more Ruby way of doing this is either:

```
puts "2+3 equals #{2+3}" # Using string interpolation
puts "2+3 equals %d" % (2 + 3) # Using sprintf-style interpolation
```

Now if you're using `irb`, that's a Read-Evaluate-Print-Loop (REPL) which means it executes everything you type in as soon as you press enter, by design. If you want to use your original code, you need to force it on one line:

```
print "2+3 equals "; print 2+3
```

Then that will work as expected. The `;` line separator is rarely used in Ruby, most style guides encourage you to split things up onto multiple lines, but if you do need to do a one-liner, this is how.

When writing code in, say a `.rb` file the return key is just used for formatting and doesn't execute any code.

Comment: On second reading, I realized I'd read too much into this and it was an example the book didn't actually want me to write in `irb` since it didn't have the `irb(main):` notation in front of it. Womp. Thanks!

Comment: "but also adds a newline" probably should be "but also conditionally adds a newline if the output doesn't already end with a newline"

Comment: `print` and `puts` also accept multiple arguments so `print 'hello', 2+3` #=> `hello5`, similarly for `puts`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use semicolon at the end of statement like this `puts "hello";puts"world"`

Answer (score -1):

You can put a semicolon after the first line, like this:

```
print "2+3 is equal to ";
print 2 + 3
```

Comment: This isn't the Ruby-way. The two lines should be written without the semicolon if they're separate lines.